# nothing happens when i emit some value to socket server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I have an expressjs server code which listen to a socket port like what you see below.

```
websocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A client just joined on', socket.id);
  websocket.on('messageIM', (message) => {
     console.log('msg:'+message)

});
});
```

my client side application is a react-native mobile project which contains a code like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
super(props); 
this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://192.168.140.51:3000/');

  }
```

and i get client connect 'A client just joined on ***' log on server console, means the connection to the server is successfully . but when i emit some variable .... nothing will happens in server side!...

```
call()=>{
 this.socket.emit('messageIM','Hi server')
}
```

means when i call above `call()` function nothing happens in server.

this are the codes i'v written in both client and server side please give some help if you have some experience with that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you used the wrong variable to listen on. The connection event returns the socket which is what you want to use. Rename `websocket.on('messageIM'` to `socket.on('messageIM'`

```
websocket.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('A client just joined on', socket.id);
  socket.on('messageIM', message => {
     console.log(`msg: ${message}`)
  });
});
```